# Error with using Forest and Tikz externalization

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, external

I can't seem to figure out why my forest externalization fails. It always works properly on the first compile, and if I clear any temporary files from my directory, but otherwise making any change to the tree and trying to recompile fails entirely with the following error:

> ./Untitled.tex:15: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'Untitled-forest-3' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'Untitled-forest-3.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linguistics, external]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
    Forest:
    
    \begin{forest}
        [VP
            [V]
            [NP]
        ]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

And I'll include the full log, in case there's something I'm missing:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-07> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfit.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryintersections.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elocalloc/elocalloc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inlinedef/inlinedef.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzexternalshared.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest-lib-linguistics.sty) (/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.for)This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.aux)This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

===== tikzexternal: \end{document} reached. Working on rescheduled images to resolve references... ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' ========

./Untitled.tex:15: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'Untitled-forest-3' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'Untitled-forest-3.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 \end{document}
                   
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.pdf (1 page, 12327 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.log.


/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -file-line-error -interaction=nonstopmode -synctex=1 -shell-escape -output-directory=/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp Untitled.tex

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Untitled.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-07> (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.geometric.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.misc.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.misc.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.symbols.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.arrows.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.callouts.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/shapes/pgflibraryshapes.multipart.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibraryfit.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryintersections.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryfpu.code.tex)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgfopts/pgfopts.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elocalloc/elocalloc.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/environ/environ.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/trimspaces/trimspaces.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/inlinedef/inlinedef.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryexternal.code.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzexternalshared.code.tex))) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/forest/forest-lib-linguistics.sty) (/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg)) (/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.for)This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' ========
===== The last system call resulted in an EMPTY output file. Maybe it is part of \ref. Rescheduling it for \end{document}. ========
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.aux)This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode

===== tikzexternal: \end{document} reached. Working on rescheduled images to resolve references... ========
===== 'mode=convert with system call': Invoking 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' ========

./Untitled.tex:15: Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "Untitled-forest-3" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{Untitled}\input{Untitled}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'Untitled-forest-3' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in 'Untitled-forest-3.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset the picture.

See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.15 \end{document}
                   
 )
(see the transcript file for additional information)</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on /Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.pdf (1 page, 12327 bytes).
SyncTeX written on /Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on /Users/vincentmariani/Desktop/.texpadtmp/Untitled.log.
```

Comment: I can offer an alternative externalization tool, Memoize, which is *almost* ready to be published. If you want to try it out, contact me via email (which you can get from my webpage).

Comment: FYI: I have recently published Memoize at CTAN.